# How can I remotely upload files to Amazon S3?

Tags: file-upload, upload, amazon-s3

I am looking for a way to transfer files from a server to Amazon S3 bucket, without first downloading the files to my computer. All of the files I plan to transfer can be accessed publicly (e.g. `http://something.com/file.ext`). Everything I tried only allows me to directly upload files from my Mac to S3.

P.S. Although I have access to windows, a Mac app that can do this would be great... or maybe a browser-based solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [this](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) PHP class ([and a net tuts tutorial on it](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/)), it works well, I've been using it for a while now. It includes bucket creation, deletion, adding files and more. You can easily add files remotely from another server, or from the same server you're running it on.